# Epsilon-Delta More Confusion

Tags: real-analysis, epsilon-delta

> Use Epsilon-Delta to prove:
>   $$
> \lim_{x \to 1} (x^2 + 3) = 4
> $$

So, we need to find a $\delta$ s.t.

$$
0 < x - 1 < \delta \; \implies \; 0 < |(x^2 + 3) - 4| < \epsilon
$$

We simplify

$$0< |(x^2 + 3) - 4| < \epsilon$$ to get $$0 < |x^2 - 1| < \epsilon$$

This is where I'm stuck. 
How do I find a delta in terms of epsilon now?

Comment: [This answer][1] talks about what's going on with this sort of calculation.


  [1]: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/687374/14972

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(x^2 + 3) - 4 = (x - 1)(x + 1) $$

First choose $\delta= 1$ so that

$x + 1 = (x - 1) + 2 \lt x - 1 + 2 \lt 1 + 2 = 3$.

Then let $\epsilon> 0$ be given, choose $\delta  = \min\{\epsilon/3, 1\}$, then if $x - 1 \lt \delta \implies (x^2 + 3) - 4 \lt \epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

You can factor $x^2-1$. From there, the condition $|x-1|<\delta$ implies that $|x+1|<\delta +2$. Can you use this to find an expression for $\delta$?

Comment: Why does it imply that?

Comment: @nomlylni The distance from $1$ to $-1$ is $2$.

Comment: $|x-1|+2<\delta+2$, and from there you have a reference to the "triangle inequality", $|a+b|\leq |a|+|b|$

Comment: So if $|x+1| < \delta +2$ and $|(x+1)||(x-1)| < \epsilon$, then $|(x+1)| < \frac{\epsilon}{|(x-1)|}$ ?

Comment: Why is my statement wrong though? Couldn't we have said what I said in my previous comment instead of $|(x+2)| < |x|+|2|$?

Comment: The thing you said immediately after "$\delta +2$ and..." is wrong. We don't know this. This is what we are trying to show. The point of an epsilon-delta proof is to give a formula for delta (usually in terms of epsilon), that makes that statement (in this case, $|x^2-1|<\epsilon$) true.

Comment: right...what i'm trying to do is find $\delta$. I still don't know how

Comment: Yes. Now, we are assuming that $|x-1|<\delta$. We know that, given only this fact, $|x+1|<\delta+2$. Now what happens if we multiply these two inequalities together? In general, if $a<b$ and $c<d$ (all positive numbers), then $ac<bd$. If we multiply the left hand sides, we get $|x^2-1|$, and on the right hand sides, we get an expression in terms of $\delta$. From there, you must simply set that right hand side equal to $\epsilon$ and you should be able to find a way to write $\delta$ in terms of $\epsilon$.

Comment: You can't write $\delta$ in terms of $\epsilon$. We have $\delta(\delta + 2) = \epsilon$. We can't write delta alone

Comment: There is no specific motivation. In epsilon delta proofs sometimes the logic seems like magic. You write what you want and notice a pattern (hopefully). In this case, writing what you want to happen ($|x^2-1|<\epsilon$) leads you to factor the left hand side, where you see an $x-1$ hanging out. But you know that you're gonna assume $|x-1|<\delta$ as part of the proof, so from there you beat $|x+1|$ with an algebra stick until it does what it's told.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my comment before you saw it. Could you explain what I asked?

Comment: You're right, the story is a bit more complicated. But you only need pick a $\delta$ such that $\delta (\delta +2)<\epsilon$. You don't need it to be equal.

Comment: We don't even know what $\epsilon$ is. How can we pick a $\delta$ s.t. it is true?

Comment: In this case, it is probably best for you to extend to case work. You consider two cases, one where $\epsilon \geq 1$, and one where $\epsilon <1$. In the first example, we simply choose $\delta$ to be something like $\frac{1}{4}$. In the second case, we choose $\delta$ to be $\frac{\epsilon}{4}$. Then $\delta (\delta +2)=\frac{\epsilon ^2}{16}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Since $\epsilon <1$ in this case, $\epsilon ^2<\epsilon$, and you can see that what we have is $<\epsilon$.

Comment: It is best to picture the epsilon-delta proof as playing a sort of game. Someone is giving you an epsilon and asking you to pick a delta such that if you can get one expression under delta, then this other expression will be under epsilon. To do this for all possible choices of epsilon, or in other words, to win this game without having to go back and forth for eternity, you use algebraic manipulation of both expressions and give a delta which is written in relation to epsilon. You show that as long as you choose delta to be that value, you'll always win the game, no matter what epsilon is.

Answer (score 0):

You want to find a function $f$ so that for any $e > 0$
$$
|x - 1| < f(e) \implies |(x^2 + 3) - 4| = |x^2 - 1| = |x + 1||x - 1| < e
$$
Since $|x - 1| < f(e) \implies |x + 1| < f(e) + 2$ you also have a
bound for the product of those factors
$$
|x + 1||x - 1| < f(e)(f(e) + 2)
$$
Now all you have to do is set $f(e)(f(e) + 2) = e$ and solve for
$f(e)$:
$$
f(e)^2 + 2f(e) = e \iff (f(e) + 1)^2 = e + 1 \iff f(e) = \sqrt{e + 1} - 1
$$
So $\delta = f(e) = \sqrt{e + 1} - 1$. As you can see, there are many ways to choose the $\delta$. I like this way because the choice feels less arbitrary.